# "Error calling method on NPObject!" in Uploadify

Tags: javascript, flash, replace, uploadify, function-prototypes

I'm using Uploadify to upload file in my CMS. Everything works fine until recently. I got an error

`Error calling method on NPObject`

on this line

`document.getElementById(jQuery(this).attr('id') + 'Uploader').startFileUpload(ID, checkComplete);`

on this part

```
uploadifyUpload:function(ID,checkComplete) {
            jQuery(this).each(function() {
                if (!checkComplete) checkComplete = false;
                document.getElementById(jQuery(this).attr('id') + 'Uploader').startFileUpload(ID, checkComplete);
            });
        },
```

I don't know why and after a day debugging and testing I found that if I remove `replace(/\&/g, '\\&')` from

```
String.prototype.escAll = function(){
    var s = this;
    return s.replace(/\./g, '\\.').replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\&/g, '\\&');
};
```

It then works again. I really don't know why.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: Please, specify a browser you use.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is in additional Javascript libraries you use.

Some libraries (for example Prototype.js or jQuery.js) change behaviour of your code. For example, you can't overload `prototype` in some cases. The result may be undefined in *clear (obvious) places* (like you use an array variable with wrong index). You should view the source code of additional libraries, probably they do with `prototype` something that breaks your code in the function you mentioned.

In my practice I had the situation when overloading of `prototype` worked incorrectly (it was *String prototype* like in your case).

So just don't use `prototype`.